# Python 3.7.7 install Numpy "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:"

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to install numpy on a macOS
Big Sur but got this error.
I've tried update pip and setuptool, also
update xcode, but the error still appears

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:


 command: /Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-install-3jq2_h06/numpy_a0d6a6e5f34d4b3b887afd79c04b5c7c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-install-3jq2_h06/numpy_a0d6a6e5f34d4b3b887afd79c04b5c7c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-wheel-hvs0y1qx
       cwd: /private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-install-3jq2_h06/numpy_a0d6a6e5f34d4b3b887afd79c04b5c7c/

...

error: Command "gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I/Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -I/Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/include -arch x86_64 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/include/python3.7m -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/private -Ibuild/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

Also when pip trying to reinstall numpy, error messages appears like this

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-install-3jq2_h06/numpy_a0d6a6e5f34d4b3b887afd79c04b5c7c/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-install-3jq2_h06/numpy_a0d6a6e5f34d4b3b887afd79c04b5c7c/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/24/2bgc31xs4w51ksff8v5kphcc0000gn/T/pip-record-4yafo15v/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/mac/opt/miniconda3/include/python3.7m/numpy Check the logs for full command output.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Show us the exact command you invoke to install numpy

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `gcc` compiler or some system library dependencies problem.

Here is mine `gcc` version (MacOS Catalina)

```
$ which gcc
```

```
/usr/bin/gcc
```

```
$ gcc --version
```

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Are your macbook architecture is `x86_64`? If that is new `ARM64` one, architecture may be a reason.

Also `build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/...` and `build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.7/...` looking pretty old (OS X 10.9?). I'm not familiar with pip build processes, but looks like `python 3.7.X` libraries don't updated long time. Newer python version is `3.9.X`. Try to use it, that may be solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to similar problem in this link (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12026). You installation tries to compile numpy on your system, which is not necessary. Try to install concrete version of numpy, e.g. `pip3 install numpy==1.19.5`